# LOCATE Built in function doesn't work when there are spaces in the search string

Tags: oracle

I'm running into a small problem with querying a CLOB field using LOCATE.

I'm searching for a specific name within the CLOB, but as soon as I add spaces to my search string it returns a 0 index.

Working Code:

```
select count(REFERENCE_#) AS AssignCount
from ARADMIN.SRMIS_REQUEST
where DATE_OCCURRED_DT is not null
and (DATE_OCCURRED_DT >= add_months(sysdate, -12) )
and ({FN LOCATE('INFO-MGMT-SRVCS.R3', "SRMIS_REQUEST"."TRACE_LOG")} > 0)
```

Non-working code:

```
select count(REFERENCE_#) AS AssignCount
from ARADMIN.SRMIS_REQUEST
where DATE_OCCURRED_DT is not null and trim(DATE_OCCURRED_DT) != ''
and (DATE_OCCURRED_DT >= add_months(sysdate, -12) )
and ({FN LOCATE('The problem has been assigned to INFO-MGMT-SRVCS.R3', "SRMIS_REQUEST"."TRACE_LOG")} > 0)
```

I've even queried the "SRMIS_REQUEST"."TRACE_LOG" and directly copied the string with spaces into my where clause to test.

The Oracle docs don't say where spaces are allowed or not.

What's wrong with my second query?

**Edit:**
I changed my query to use `instr()` insetead of `LOCATE()` and it works.

Comment: What is this `{}` syntax?  Is this a SQLLite thing?  I don't think oracle is the correct tag.

Comment: Hmm, I was using it from an in-house guide in Oracle SQL Developer version 1.0. Interestingly enough when I upgraded to 3.x I got syntax errors which is when I switched to instr().